# Border radius on two corners causes visual glitch CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, webkit, chromium

The glitch:

[image]

How it should look

[image]

Edit: apparently the bar wasn't showing up on my example, so I updated it.
[Minimum example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-e8z1pz?file=style.css,App.tsx)

[Github repo if StackBlitz not working](https://github.com/Konglomneshued/growing-bar.git)

Sorry for the confusion, this is my minimum example and not my project.

You will see the glitch after about 4 seconds or so.  The bar will just render some vertical piece on the left and then it glitches in and out.

Now, if you go into index.css/style.css in StackBlitz and change the styles from

```
.innerBar {
  ...

  border-top-left-radius: .25em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .25em;
}
```

to

```
.innerBar {
  ...

  border-radius: .25em;
}
```

it will render properly.  However, if you look at index.css at the bottom I have a class for when the bar is full because I only want to round the right side corners when it's full.

I've tried messing around with the border radius on the outer div (the bar) and the inner div (the inner bar or slider).  That's how I found out what was causing it.

Edit: I tried zooming in on my example only to notice that doing so removes the artifact.  Upon restarting the bar growth at normal zoom I can see it again.

It renders correctly on Firefox but not on any Chrome browser I've tried.  I need it to work on Chrome because I'm making an Electron app.

Comment: did you try -webkit-*?

Comment: We’re unlikely to clone a repo in order to wade through a whole project in order to reproduce your problem, and then track down the relevant html elements and css in order to help you. It’s your responsibility to isolate the specific, minimal html and css to allow us to reproduce the problem you’re facing. Please, minimise the work required to help you, read the “*[ask]*,” and “*[mcve]*” guidance.

Comment: @JohnDole I don't see options for -webkit-border-radius selectors in VS Code.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @user21338683 - put your minimum example in a StackBlitz or other REPL and provide that link to your working example.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had tried to create a StackBlitz before using Chrome and it wasn't working (still isn't).  But I made one on Firefox and kept the Github repo in case the REPL does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just let the outer `.bar` do the rounded corners and **hide any overflow**. Then your `.innerBar` doesn’t need any rounded corners at all!

```
.bar {
  border-radius: .25em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.innerBar {
  border-radius: 0;   /* this is the default value */
}
```